# Python - Render object with transparent background

Tags: python

I want to render an object with transparent background with blender-python script, but I don't know how to get the transparent background.

My script is:

```
context = bpy.context
bpy.ops.import_scene.obj(filepath=file_loc)
scene = bpy.context.scene
scene.render.filepath = 'my_render.png'
bpy.ops.render.render("EXEC_DEFAULT", write_still=True)
```

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to enable the *Transparent* option that you would normally activate in the *Film* panel which can be found in the *Render* tab, if you where using the GUI.

```
bpy.context.scene.render.film_transparent = True
```

You can also access the parameter using the scene name (case sensitive) :

```
bpy.data.scenes["Scene"].render.film_transparent = True
```

Also make sure that the file format stores the alpha channel.

```
bpy.context.scene.render.image_settings.color_mode = 'RGBA'
```